# How to make buttons sunken after being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-experience

I have a multiple set of buttons which are clicked to show that they are selected.I have already successfully achieved that.But the problem is the buttons rise again after mouse up.

I need the buttons to stay pressed after the mouse leaves them.

#### Screenshot :

[image]

#### Code :

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1),
  /* gradient effects */
  0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
.button span {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  background-image:
  /* gloss gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2))),
  /* dark outside gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3)), color-stop(20%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(80%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3))),
  /* light inner gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))),
  /* diagonal line pattern */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 100% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px #fff,
  /* top highlight */
  0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
  /* bottom edge */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  color: #3A474D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20', 'PT Sans Narrow';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}
.button span:hover {
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1), 0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128, 128, 128, .6);
  /* shadow */
}
.button:active span {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  /* depth of button press */
}
.button span:after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #97A63A;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<a class="button">
  <span>select me </span>
</a>
```

Comment: is using javascript/jquery fine?

Comment: see my updated answer which toggles active using purely javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the full code below for a version based on jQuery, one based on vanilla JS and one using only HTML & CSS to achieve the desired effect.

You can also play around with the code at the following Fiddles:

- [**jQuery version**](https://jsfiddle.net/nap99ev8/7/)
- [**JS version without jQuery**](https://jsfiddle.net/nap99ev8/6/)
- [**HTML/CSS only version**](https://jsfiddle.net/nap99ev8/8/)

---

## jQuery version :

**HTML :**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<a class="button">
  <span>select me </span>
</a>
```

**CSS :**

```
   .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1),
  /* gradient effects */
  0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

.button span {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  background-image:
  /* gloss gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2))),
  /* dark outside gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3)), color-stop(20%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(80%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3))),
  /* light inner gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))),
  /* diagonal line pattern */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 100% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px #fff,
  /* top highlight */
  0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
  /* bottom edge */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  color: #3A474D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20', 'PT Sans Narrow';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}

.button span:hover {
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.pressed {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1), 0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128, 128, 128, .6);
  /* shadow */
}

.button.pressed span {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  /* depth of button press */
}

.button span:after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #97A63A;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('pressed');
});
```

---

## JS version without jQuery :

**HTML :**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<a class="button">
  <span>select me </span>
</a>
```

**CSS :**

```
 .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1),
  /* gradient effects */
  0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

.button span {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  background-image:
  /* gloss gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2))),
  /* dark outside gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3)), color-stop(20%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(80%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3))),
  /* light inner gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))),
  /* diagonal line pattern */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 100% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px #fff,
  /* top highlight */
  0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
  /* bottom edge */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  color: #3A474D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20', 'PT Sans Narrow';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}

.button span:hover {
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.pressed {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1), 0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128, 128, 128, .6);
  /* shadow */
}

.button.pressed span {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  /* depth of button press */
}

.button span:after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #97A63A;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

**JS :**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.classList.toggle('pressed');        
    });
});
```

---

## HTML/CSS only version :

**HTML :**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<button class="button">
<input type="checkbox" id="selectme" />
<span>
  <label for="selectme">select me </label>
</span>
</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.button {
  margin-left: -5000px;
}

.button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1),
  /* gradient effects */
  0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
.button label {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  background-image:
  /* gloss gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2))),
  /* dark outside gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3)), color-stop(20%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(80%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.3))),
  /* light inner gradient */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))),
  /* diagonal line pattern */
  -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 100% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(40%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, #D2D2D1), color-stop(60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px #fff,
  /* top highlight */
  0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
  /* bottom edge */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  color: #3A474D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20', 'PT Sans Narrow';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}
.button label:hover {
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button input:checked + span {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(128, 128, 128, 1), 0px 4px rgba(118, 118, 118, 1), 0px 5px rgba(108, 108, 108, 1), 0px 6px rgba(98, 98, 98, 1), 0px 7px rgba(88, 88, 88, 1), 0px 8px rgba(78, 78, 78, 1), 0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128, 128, 128, .6);
  /* shadow */
}

.button input:checked + span label {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  /* depth of button press */
}

.button label:after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #AEBF3B;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #97A63A;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

**JS :**

```
/* CSS only means that no JS code is required at all! */
```

Comment: upvote because of the html/css only version. Nice work

Answer (score 3):

First, decorate your `css` styles that use `:active` attribute with an alias class like

```
.button:active, .button-active{
...
}

.button:active span, .button-active span{
...
}
```

then make a `onclick` event handler which manually toggles the `class`

```
function toggleActive(element){
   element.classList.toggle('button-active');
}
```

```js
function toggleActive(element){
   element.classList.toggle('button-active');
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #A7A9AC;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(.34, rgba(230,237,241,.05)),
        color-stop(.67, rgba(230,237,241,0)));
    -webkit-background-size: 5px 5px;
}

#pagegradient {
  background-image:
        -webkit-gradient(
            radial, 
            50% -50, 
            300, 
            50% 0, 
            0, 
            from(rgba(230, 237, 241, 0)), 
            to(rgba(230, 237, 241, 0.8)));
    
  height:100%;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 600px;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
    
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
} 

.button span {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    
    background-image: 
        /* gloss gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left bottom, 
            left top, 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2))),
        
        /* dark outside gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3))),
        
        /* light inner gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))),        
        
        /* diagonal line pattern */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            0% 100%, 
            100% 0%, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(40%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(40%,#D2D2D1), 
            color-stop(60%,#D2D2D1), 
            color-stop(60%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    
        -webkit-box-shadow:
            0px -1px #fff, /* top highlight */
            0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF; /* bottom edge */
    
    -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
    
    color: #3A474D;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20','PT Sans Narrow';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 32px;
    
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}

        .button span:hover {
            color: #AEBF3B;
            text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button:active, .button-active{
            -webkit-box-shadow: 
                0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1),
                0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
                0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
                0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
                0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
                0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
                0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128,128,128,.6); /* shadow */
        }

        .button:active span, .button-active span{
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px); /* depth of button press */
        }

    .button span:after {
        content: ">";
        display: block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
    
        position: absolute;
        right: 14px;
        top: 12px;    
        
        font-family: 'Cabin';
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #AEBF3B;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #97A63A;
        font-size: 26px;
    }
```

```html
<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<div id="pagegradient"></div>

    <a class="button" onclick="toggleActive(this)">
        <span>select me </span>
           </a>
```

Comment: Just a note that `toggle` is not supported by IE 9. I don't care about IE 9...but if the OP does, he/she may need to write a simple polyfill.

Comment: @rnevius, :) thanks for the heads up. If it turns out he cares, Ill look for a work-around

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it without JavaScript. Try `:checked` pseudo class and adjacent sibling selector (`+`):

```css
label {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #d00;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#checkbox:checked + label {
  background: #600;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">select me </label>
```

I also did a little change to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RN63Y/1264/)

You can also make nice look single selection:

```css
label {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #d00;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label {
  background: #600;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group" id="option1">
<label for="option1">select 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="option2">
<label for="option2">select 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="option3">
<label for="option3">select 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="option4">
<label for="option4">select 4</label>
```

Comment: @rnevius It's 2015 now, CSS3 is available everywhere :)

Comment: Definitely. I prefer CSS over JavaScript every time. This is a great answer.